# Using Object.assign when updating document fields with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am making a website where users can create new projects. To create the project users have to fill in a form with all the project info. Inside this form is a file input field, users can select images and documents with this. My code loops thru all the files and stores them inside the Firebase Storage. That part of the code works perfectly, except the part where i am trying to populate the document fields with that data.

I tried this by using `Object.assign()` inside the Firebase `.update()`.
Whenever this piece of code gets triggered it throws this error:

> Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom File object (found in field image)

I know that the `Object.assign` is the problem here because it works without it. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this problem.

This is the part of the code that throws the error:

```
firestore.collection('projects').doc(res.id)
    .update(Object.assign(this.values, {
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
        createdBy: '/users/' + firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.email,
        approved: false
    }))
    .then(res => {
       console.log(res)
       this.$toast.success('Project changes saved', { icon: 'mdi-check-bold' })
     }).catch((err) => {
         this.$toast.error(err.message, { icon: 'mdi-alert-circle' })
         console.log(err)
       })
```

This is the function that i call on submit:

```
submit () {
  this.overlay = true

      firestore.collection('projects').add({})
          .then((res) => {
            Promise.all(
              fileKeys.map((key, index) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  if (!this.values[key]) {
                    resolve(this.values[key])
                  } else {
                    if (typeof this.values[key][0] === 'undefined') {
                      const file = this.values[key]
                      const ref = storage.ref(`/projects/${res.id}/${file.name}`)

                      this.uploadHandler(file, ref, index).then((downloadURL) => {
                        if (downloadURL) {
                          this.values[key] = {
                            url: downloadURL,
                            fullPath: ref.fullPath,
                            name: file.name || '',
                            size: file.size || '',
                            type: file.type || ''
                          }

                          resolve(this.values[key])
                        } else {
                          reject()
                        }
                      })

                    } else {
                      const fileCollection = [];

                      Promise.all(
                        (this.values[key]).map((file) => {
                          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            const ref = storage.ref(`/projects/${res.id}/${file.name}`)

                            this.uploadHandler(file, ref, index).then((downloadURL) => {
                              if (downloadURL) {
                                fileCollection.push({
                                  url: downloadURL,
                                  fullPath: ref.fullPath,
                                  name: file.name || '',
                                  size: file.size || '',
                                  type: file.type || '',
                                  height: '',
                                  width: ''
                                })
                              }

                              resolve(downloadURL)
                            }).catch((e) => {
                              reject(e)
                            })
                          })
                        })
                      ).then(() => {
                        this.values[key] = fileCollection.length > 0 ? fileCollection : null
                        resolve(fileCollection)
                      })
                    }
                  }
                })
              })
            )
            firestore.collection('projects').doc(res.id).update(Object.assign(this.values, { createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date(), createdBy: '/users/' + firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.email, approved: false }))
              .then(res => {
              console.log(res)
              this.$toast.success('Project changes saved', { icon: 'mdi-check-bold' })
            }).catch((err) => {
              this.$toast.error(err.message, { icon: 'mdi-alert-circle' })
              console.log(err)
            })
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log('error')
          })
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the object you passed to `update()` contains a File object as one of its properties, which is not accepted.  You should only be passing objects to Firestore that have common JavaScript types, or Timestamps, or DocumentReferences.

This probably means that `this.values` contains at least one File object prior to calling `Object.assign()`.  (The code is kind of difficult to follow, so I can't immediately see what that might be.)  What you will have to do instead is make sure that you're composing an object that doesn't contain File objects.  If it was your intent to store an uploaded file in Cloud Firestore, that's probably not a good idea anyway, since you could easily exceed the max document size of 1MB.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there a way to turn the File Object into something that Firebase does accept?

Comment: You're going to have to figure out exactly what you want to store in its place, if anything at all.  I don't know what that's going to be for your case.

Comment: I am still a beginner when it comes to this so i dont know if it is possible but i want to convert the File Object into a normal JSON object so i can store it in Firebase.

Comment: I think you should look into ways to read the file and work with its contents.  Maybe start with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader